# c++: Linked list error " Access violation reading location"

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm trying to create a function for my linked list that adds a node to the end of my program. I'm getting an error when using the the link forward in my node that states

> Access violation reading location 0xccccccd8

It's pointing the line at the start of the while loop inside my add function. How can I fix this?

My add, print and showList function:

```
void List::Add(char data, char* dataString)
{
Node* n5;
n5 = new Node;

n5->data = data;
n5->dataString = dataString;

while (nodes->linkf != NULL)
{
    nodes = nodes->linkf;
    
}
nodes->linkb = n5;

//n5->linkb = List::nodes;

//n5->linkf = NULL;
}

void List::showList(int dir)
{
if (dir==1){
  while (nodes !=NULL)
   {
        Print();
        nodes = nodes->linkf;
   }
   cout<<"\n";
}

if (dir==0){
   while(nodes != NULL)
   {
    Print();
    nodes = nodes->linkb;
   }
   cout<<"\n";
   }

}

void List::Print()
{
    cout<<" \n";
    cout<<nodes->data;
    cout<<nodes->dataString;
    cout<<" \n";

 }
```

Node and List classes:

```
class Node
{
public:
    Node(){
        char data[5];
        dataString=new(char[10]);
    }
    ~Node(){};

    Node *linkb;
    char data;
    char* dataString;
    Node *linkf;
};

class List{
public:
Node* nodes;
List(){}
void Add(char data, char*dataString);
void showList(int);
void Print();
string entry;
};
```

Main:

```
Node *n1, *n2, *n3, *n4 ;
List *l1;

int direction;
char choice;
char data;
char* dataString = "";
char dataBuffer[30];

List myList;
n1 = new(Node);
n2 = new(Node);
n3 = new(Node);
n4 = new(Node);
string entry= "";
l1 =new(List);

cout << "Please input the data: " << endl;
cin >> data;

cout << "Please input the data string: " << endl;
cin >> dataBuffer;

dataString = &dataBuffer[0];




n1->linkb = NULL;
n1->data='C';
n1->dataString="ats ";
n1->linkf = n2;

n2->linkb = n1;
n2->data='L';
n2->dataString="ike ";
n2->linkf = n3;

n3->linkb = n4;
n3->data='F';
n3->dataString="ish ";
n3->linkf = NULL;

n4->linkb = n2;
n4->data='D';
n4->dataString="ont ";
n4->linkf = NULL;

l1->nodes = n1;
myList.Add(data, dataString);


cout<<"\nShow linked list Forward (F) or Backward (B): ";
cin>>choice;
if (choice == 'F')
    {
    direction=1;
    l1->nodes=n1;
    l1->showList(direction);
    }

    else if (choice=='B')
    {
    direction=0;
    l1->nodes=n3;
    l1->showList(direction);
    }

      else
      {
      cout<<"INVALID ENTRY !";
      exit(1);

      }
delete (n1);
delete (n2);
delete (n3);
delete (n4);
```

Comment: What is `showList`? Please post a [MCVE].

Comment: Use std::string, not char arrays and char*!

Comment: What do you think you are doing here? `Node(){
        char data[5];
        dataString=new(char[10]);
    }`

Comment: I added the other functions showList and Print.

Comment: Probably not the cause, but you have a typo here `n4->linkb = n2;`.

Comment: I added the data and dataString in the constructor by mistake the program works without them. As for using strings it's a project requirement to use a char and char* for the data inside the Node.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio?

Comment: No that's not a typo and yes I'm using visual studios.

Comment: @EoinCoogan Visual Studio has one of the most powerful and easiest to use debuggers. Use it.

Comment: I'll never understand why this online community is so toxic.

Comment: @EoinCoogan this community is not toxic, we're just pushing you to the right direction. The VS debugger is a great tool and it will help you to find out what's going on and it will also help you in the future for other problems. You only need to invest some time (really not much) to learn the basics of the debugger. Questions that are dumped here saying basically "my code doesn't work" are generally not well received. Please read this [ask].

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code you never set your pointers to `null`, which means they'll just take whatever garbage value is in memory at time of construction. In your `node` class constructor, you should initialise all pointers to `null`:

```
    Node()
        : linkb(nullptr), linkf(nullptr)
    {
        char data[5];
        dataString=new(char[10]);
    }
```

You should do the same for the `list` class

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

When you call `myList.Add(data, dataString);`, the content of `myList.nodes` is undetermined because nobody has ever initialized it.

```
void List::Add(char data, char* dataString)
{
  Node* n5;
  n5 = new Node;

  n5->data = data;
  n5->dataString = dataString;

  while (nodes->linkf != NULL)    // nodes is undetermined here and therefore
                                  // dereferencing it crashes the program
  {
    nodes = nodes->linkf;

  }
  nodes->linkb = n5;

  //n5->linkb = List::nodes;

  //n5->linkf = NULL;
}
```

If found this out in 30 seconbds using (guess what) the debugger.

But there are most likely more problems elsewhere in your code, the whole code looks fishy.

Answer (score 0):

So I just solved it although there's still a lot of errors and badly written code it technically works. When I was declaring the nodes equal to n1 in main I was using a different List object to the add function.

My code before:

```
l1->nodes = n1;
myList.Add(data, dataString);
```

My code now:

```
l1->nodes = n1;
l1->Add(data, dataString);
```